# Move table row in another section with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a html table in which i have two sections:-

(i)Upper section

(ii)Lower section

Both section have some rows that could be moved upper to lower or vice-versa according to the option selected by the user from drop-down.

I want to move a row into lower section with a animation when I select lower option from the  Upper drop-down  and vice-versa.

Another thing :- Anyone can help in animation effects when table sorting is performed. I don't want to use any plugin( i am using java-script sort() function)

please see my code and suggest what i have to do for this.

I am pasting my sample code here please have a look at my code:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table class="animatedTable">
<tbody>
<tr style="background-color:white;" class="rowUpperSection">
<td>Upper Section</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:green" class="upperRow">
<td>row 1 upper section</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>
Choose
</option>
<option>
Go to lower
</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:gray" class="upperRow">
<td>row 2 upper section</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>
Choose
</option>
<option>
Go to lower
</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:green" class="upperRow">
<td>row 3 upper section</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>
Choose
</option>
<option>
Go to lower
</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="blankRow separtor" style="background-color:white;"><td><br/></td></tr>
<tr style="background-color:white;" class="rowLowerSection">
<td>Lower Section</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:gray" class="lowerRow">
<td>row 1 lower section</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>
Choose
</option>
<option>
Go to Upper
</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:green" class="lowerRow">
<td>row 1 lower section</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>
Choose
</option>
<option>
Go to Upper
</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:gray" class="lowerRow">
<td>row 1 lower section</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>
Choose
</option>
<option>
Go to Upper
</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
$('select').change(function(){
var _this = $(this),
row = _this.parents('tr');
    if(row.hasClass('upperRow'))
    {
        row.removeClass('upperRow').addClass('lowerRow');
        row.remove();
        $('.rowLowerSection').after(row);
    }
    else{
        row.removeClass('lowerRow').addClass('upperRow');
        row.remove();
        $('.rowUpperSection').after(row);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've forgotten the snippet you've already tried. Please add it to your question.

Comment: I have tried with .remove() from one section and .after() to append into another section with some fadeIn efects. But these are not much interective. I want some interaction animation that show the row is moving one sectin to another

Comment: Please re-read my comment : ).

Comment: Yes bro i have read and you can say forgotten or I think i my try was not that I want that's why I am here for solution

Comment: As you wish... It would be a lot easier for us to build on your code, starting from scratch feels rather - you know - "plz give me teh codez" question.

Comment: :) wait please. i know "plz give....." :)

Comment: @Teemu please have a look at code now. I have added the javsacript code

Comment: You could clone a row for animation, and remove the clone after animation is finished. Something like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71qLbky3/) (only moves from upper section are animated in the fiddle).

Comment: @Teemu thanks very much bro. It looks nice. i have to do some customization in this because I have to sort the table according to first td value and then place the new coming row. It is nice though

Comment: @Teemu bro paste this as answer I want to give you +1.